# JSF access to the "var" attribute value from dataTable from jsp

Tags: jsf

I'm using JSF 1.1. I have a JSP page with a

```html
    ....
    <t:dataTable id="data"
       styleClass="scrollerTable"
       headerClass="standardTable_Header"
       footerClass="standardTable_Header"
       columnClasses="col1,col2,col3"
       var="product"
       value="#{beanProduct.listOfProducts}"
       preserveDataModel="false"
       rows="10"
    >
    ....
```

The `#{product}` has a attribute named `state`. If its value is "pending", then I want to display a `<h:commandButton>`, else I display nothing.

How can I get the value of `#{product.state}` in JSP scriptlet code?

I tried the next:

```html
    ....
    <h:column>
       <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="#{messages['list']}" />
       </f:facet>
       <%
           // ----> In this point, I want know the value of "product.state"
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
       Application app = context.getApplication();  
       ValueBinding binding = app.createValueBinding("#{product.state}"); 
       Object valueOfProduct = binding.getValue(context);
       String stateProduct = (String)valueOfProduct;
       if (stateProduct.equals("pending")) {
       %>
       <h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{beanProduct.Item}" action="#{beanProduct.sending">
        <f:attribute name="idProduct" value="#{product.id}" />
            </h:commandButton>
           </h:panelGrid>
           <%
           }
           else {
           %>
           // Do nothing.
           <%
       }
       %>
    </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

But it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are trying to mix two completely different programming paradigms. Generally, you should not use `<% /*code*/ %>` scriptlets at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "rendered" attribute instead:

```
  <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="#{messages['list']}" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:commandButton rendered="#{product.pending}" value="Send" 
                      actionListener="#{beanProduct.Item}" 
                      action="#{beanProduct.sending">
        <f:attribute name="idProduct" value="#{product.id}" />
     </h:commandButton>

  </h:column>
```

Mixing JSF and JSP like this won't work because dataTable var will not be available at the time your embedded code is executed. Also it is not a recommended practice.